# Nearest neighbour interpolation not working in ImageMagick

Tags: resize, pixelation, imagemagick

I want to display an image and have the pixels big and clearly visible. As it's common to display scaled image with some form of smooth filtering, the best option is to scale up the image resolution without interpolation (i.e. nearest). I have quite a few and need automation, hence ImageMagick.

I'm certain I've done this before and hit the same problem, but this time Google isn't helping. I vaguely remember the order of the arguments can be quite important here but I've tried every permutation and the output is the same.

The following simply doesn't work. It resizes the image correctly but it's all blurry:

```
convert from.png -interpolate Nearest -resize 800% to.png
```

What am I missing?

---

Example:

I start with [image]

I get this [image]

But want this [image]

---

Related links:

- [ImageMagick v6 Examples - Simple Interpolation Methods](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/#interpolate_simple)
- [ImageMagick: Command-line Options - interpolate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interpolate)

Comment: to obtain what you want, you should *disable* interpolation.

Comment: @Vincent I was under the impression that using `Integer` or `Nearest` should disable it. Is there another way?

Comment: I seriously don't have a clue for imagemagick, but I know that I need to disable interpolation when I want a pixelated enlargement in Photoshop... :)

Comment: Any number of reasons: the images could have been made/provided by someone else, the sample could have been produced by a different application, ...

Comment: @DumbNic MichaelSchumacher is correct. I created it with gimp, but I want to use imagemagick for gui-less automation.

Comment: "disable interpolation" regardless of what the option says in photoshop, the act of determining pixel values in the larger image that didn't previously exist in your smaller image is called interpolation.  In other words, "scaling up" an image necessarily involves interpolation of some flavor.

Answer (score 17):

Silly me. I found a solution in my bash history. I needed to set `-filter point`.

```
convert from.png -interpolate Nearest -filter point -resize 800% to.png
```

The default filter appears to be Cubic for me. Interestingly, `-interpolate Nearest` doesn't seem to affect the output at all and may not be needed above. I'd love to know why and won't accept this as *the* answer.

Comment: _ImageMagick_ can be funny [sometimes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interpolate) - as when the doc shows non uppercase parameters but they must still be used as `convert -list interpolate` lists the what is available and it's all uppercase. Note the default is _Bilinear_. As you mention after a few tests I can't say it changes anything that I can see loll. There is mention that this is most important for distort/transform etc. Cheers!

Comment: This did not work for me, however changing `Nearest` to `Integer` made it all work. Thank you for the `-filter point` hint!